# Android apps that support the hierarchical search in meta-tagged files

Tags: android, image-viewer, metadata

I am looking for an Android app that can search inside meta-taged graphics files (primarily jpg, png) not only by flat tags (primarily IPTC and MWG), but also by hierarchical tags.

For Windows I am using FastPhotoTagger, which is more than enough for all basic operations
https://fastphototagger.sourceforge.net/hierarchical.html

However for Android tablet the app ain't quite there yet, as far as the  hierarchical search is concerned.

So I'd really appreciate any recommendations from  someone who's in the know. Preference shall be given to freeware with no ads.

Thanks in advance.